# Masculine κραδίας? Methodology for figuring out if a lemma is fictional?

Tags: ancient-greek, dialects

There are projects like Project Perseus and PROIEL that have created open-source databases in which the grammatical structures of Greek and Latin texts are completely analyzed. They were made by humans, and although generally pretty accurate, they contain the types of mistakes that you would expect, including many that could just as easily have been made by a scribe of a past era. One of the things they do is to provide a dictionary lemma for each word, and I'm interested in figuring out whether some of these are mistakes. For example, Perseus in one spot provides the lemma ἐυκνψμις, which should have been ἐυκνήμις.

In the less obvious cases, what is a good methodology for figuring out whether something is a real lemma or some kind of mistake or invention of the person who did the analysis? As an example, in Iliad 8.147, we have "ἀλλὰ τόδ’ αἰνὸν ἄχος κραδίην καὶ θυμὸν ἱκάνει·" Here Perseus has κραδίην lemmatized as masculine κραδίας. Of the 15 times that the word κραδίην occurs in Homer, 12 are lemmatized as καρδία, the other 3 as κραδίας. [Cunliffe](https://ia904701.us.archive.org/8/items/CunliffeHomericLexicon/cunliffe.html) doesn't mention a masculine κραδίας. CGL doesn't say anything about it either, but I suppose it could be some kind of dialectical form. They do list κραδία/κραδίη. It would seem reasonable to me to lemmatize this form as καρδία, κραδία, or κραδίη, but I'm trying to figure out what is a good methodology for determining whether κραδίας is simply a mistake. I don't see anything grammatical in 8.147 that would suggest it's being treated as masculine. The fact that CGL doesn't list it doesn't necessarily mean that it's not real, since there are lots of dialects and periods of Greek, and they can't address them all. You'd think Cunliffe would have mentioned it, but maybe there is some rational reason why the Perseus worker would disagree with Cunliffe. It seems odd to me that they would have done this three times in Homer if it was completely fictional, but maybe once they'd done it once, their data entry software started popping it up again as a suggestion. (The project is old and there is nobody presently maintaining it.) I haven't come across anything that looks like a clearcut 3rd declension form of κραδίας, but maybe I haven't looked hard enough.

Is there, for example, some 19th century reference book like "Lexicon of really obscure dialectical forms of words in ancient Greek?" I would think that people working on inscriptions would also need specialized reference works, since the Greek in inscriptions is often so different from literary Greek.